# How to pass arguments with window.open in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, parameter-passing, window.open

I am trying to pass arguments with my exe but it's not working.

Below steps I followed to calling exe:

1. Register my exe in Registry Editor:

   Path: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callapp\shell\open\command`

In the command simply added the exe path in the Default like below

```
"C:\dummyApp\abc.exe" "%1"
```

2. From the class component I am calling registry editor like below:

   componentDidMount() {

   ```
   window.open(`callapp: ${ip} ${port}`,"_self");
   ```

   }

**Error** In the exe side I am getting the data into below format

Program args - 0  callapp:%20ip%20port

**Expected Scenario is:**

Program args - 0 ip

Program args - 1 port

If anyone can help into this please.